# When installing from Software Center, how can I choose my admin account from the "Authentication Required" box?

Tags: permissions, software-center, sudo

I recently had Ubuntu 18.04 installed on my iMac at work. Our IT guy installed it, and created an admin account for himself (`adminIT`) and one for me (`adminme`). For normal work, I use a third non-admin, non-`sudo` account (`user`). I can execute `sudo` commands with `adminme`. However, when attempting to install programs through the Software app, I'm prompted with an Authentication Required box that will only allow me to use `adminIT`. I can't choose `adminme`, which we have verified has exactly the same privileges (groups, etc.) as `adminIT`.

How can we go about fixing this? The IT guy is just as baffled as I am. We've tried logging into `adminme`, installing something, and then coming back to `user` and trying again (in hopes that it just defaults to the most recently used admin account), but that didn't work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is the output of `id` for each admin account:

```
$ id adminme
uid=1002(adminme) gid=1002(adminme) groups=1002(adminme),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),116(lpadmin),126(sambashare)

$ id adminIT
uid=1000(adminIT) gid=1000(adminIT) groups=1000(adminIT),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),116(lpadmin),126(sambashare)
```

Comment: If you've installed the software in the adminme account, why would you need/want to reinstall it in the user account?

Comment: @heynnema I wouldn't; I only use the user account for everyday work, however. Switching the adminme account for GUI installation would be a bit tedious. I'm just looking for a solution where I can install software straight from Software Center on my user account by entering the password for adminme.